# ggmap legend not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggmap

I have two dataframes both recording the top 10 stations riders went. One is for casual rider, the other one is for member rider. Both dataframes contain column 'station','freq','latitude','longitude'. I'm able to use ggmap to plot the graph showing the locations of the stations from both dataframes, but not able to show the legend.
R scripe is showing below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rstudioapi)
library(ggmap)

map_location <- c (lon =  -87.623177, lat = 41.881832)

chicago_map_zoom <- get_map (location = map_location, 
                        maptype = 'roadmap', 
                        color='bw', 
                        source='google', 
                        zoom=13,
)

chicago_plot <- ggmap(chicago_map_zoom) +
  geom_point (data = casual_top_station,
              aes (x = longitude,
                   y = latitude),
              color = "red",
              shape = 15,
              alpha = 0.5,
              size = 3) +
  geom_point (data = member_top_station,
              aes (x = longitude,
                   y = latitude),
              color = "blue",
              shape = 16,
              alpha = 0.5,
              size = 2) +
  scale_color_identity (name = "Subscription type",
                        breaks = c("red","blue"),
                        labels = c("Casual","Member"),
                        guide = "legend") +
  theme (axis.ticks = element_blank(),
         axis.text = element_blank(),
         axis.title = element_blank()) +
  labs (title = "Top 10 casual and member rider stations",
        subtitle = "Both start and end stations")
```

Result graph: [Chicago_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9jfu.png)

Comment: If you want a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. move `color="red"` and `color="blue"` inside `aes(..., color = ...)` and you will get your legend.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It works! But now the shape of the spot in my legend is not reflecting correctly to the shape I used. And putting the shape in the aes gives me error "Error in `scale_f()`: ! A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape"

Comment: When you add it to `aes` with a string, it adds a legend. However, adding `color = "blue"` in `aes` has no effect on the color. If you want it blue, keep it out of `aes` as blue. What you put in `aes` is what you want it to look like in your legend. For example, you might have `geom_point(data, aes(x, y, color = "Casual", shape = "Casual"), color = "blue", shape = 16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `scale_color_identity` ... to set the values for color, shape and size I would suggest to first an `id` column to your data.frames
which could then be mapped on aesthetics inside `aes`. Afterwards set your desired colors, shapes and sizes via the `scale_xxx_manual` family of functions.

Using some fake data for the points:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

casual_top_station <- data.frame(
  longitude = -87.65,
  latitude = 41.9
)

member_top_station <- data.frame(
  longitude = -87.65,
  latitude = 41.86
)

casual_top_station$id <- "Casual"
member_top_station$id <- "Member"
legend_title <- "Subscription type"

base <- ggmap(chicago_map_zoom) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Casual = "red", Member = "blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(Casual = 15, Member = 16)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(Casual = 3, Member = 2)) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Top 10 casual and member rider stations",
    subtitle = "Both start and end stations",
    color = legend_title, shape = legend_title, size = legend_title
  )

base + 
  geom_point(
    data = casual_top_station,
    aes(
      x = longitude,
      y = latitude,
      color = id, shape = id, size = id
    ),
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = member_top_station,
    aes(
      x = longitude,
      y = latitude,
      color = id, shape = id, size = id
    ),
    alpha = 0.5
  )
```

[image]

Also, to simplify your code further I would suggest to bind both data frames by row using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows` which would allow to add your points via just one `geom_point`.

```r
top_station <- dplyr::bind_rows(casual_top_station, member_top_station)

base + 
  geom_point(
    data = top_station,
    aes(
      x = longitude,
      y = latitude,
      color = id, shape = id, size = id
    ), alpha = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem! I didn't know we have scale_color_manual, scale_shape_manual and scale_size_manual. And thanks for giving me the idea to combine to dataframes!